# Is there a way I can have standard output show on my terminal screen AND get redirected to a file?

Tags: linux, redirectstandardoutput

The question says it all.  Is there any way I can have standard output appear on my terminal screen and get inputted into a file as well?

I use tcsh on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

```
$command | tee $output_file
```

`man tee` for more information.

Comment: What if my `$command` is an executable I made with C?  I want the results of the `printf()` functions in my code to display on the terminal and go to the output file.  Does `tee` work for that?

Comment: Yup.  Anything that goes to `stdout` gets sent to `stdout` as well as the file.

Comment: Well, there is added complexity if you want to do thing like redirect `stderr`, but in those kinds of cases, I would highly recommend using a Bourne-style shell rather than a C-shell derivative.

Comment: I'm trying it and it doesn't work.  Does it work with `nohup`?  I am also using `nohup`.

Comment: It should.  Try it on any different shell.  C-shells don't lend themselves very easily to this sort of thing.  Perhaps something simple like sh or ksh?  Hold on.  Installing tcsh.

Comment: `nohup ls -l | tee blong.out` works fine here under `tcsh`.